Determine in which cluster goes a new element with scipy linkage
I have the following program where data is a pandas.DataFrame:
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage

Z = linkage(data, method='ward', metric='euclidean')
clusters = fcluster(Z, 2, criterion='maxclust')

Now, considering a set of new elements that have the same structure as data, how do i know which cluster do they belong to?
